# jQuery $.isNumeric throws error on console

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

Im having a problem using an isNumeric jQuery function to check if a variable is a number.

I am getting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'isNumeric'
```

Here is my code

```
var scroll = 4;
$.isNumeric(scroll);
  if (false) {
     scroll = 0;
     tabChange(menuTab, page, scroll);
  } else {
     tabChange(menuTab, page, scroll);
  }
```

I thought this may be caused by having my code being run before jQuery has loaded but this is not the case.

Also the jQuery documentation is very unclear to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version of jQuery are you using? `.isNumeric()` was added in 1.7, and if you're using an earlier version it's not available, which would give that error.

Another possibility is that you have Prototype or some other JS library running as well - try using `jQuery.isNumeric(scroll);` instead of the `$` notation.

Comment: You got it Joe, i was working on someone elses work that had jQuery 1.6.2, but i didnt bother to check. Thanks :)